# Java convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a properties file with Asian translations in it, which I believe is saved as ISO-8859-1.  I'm trying to convert them to UTF-8. So `è­¦å:` would equal `警告:`

I've tried several methods listed on this site as well as some other sites but have had no luck.

```
byte[] isoBytes = line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] utf8 = new String(isoBytes, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

---

```
CharBuffer charBuf = null;
Charset isocharset = Charset.forName("iso-8859-1");
CharsetDecoder isoDecoder = Charset.forName("iso-8859-1").newDecoder();
CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
byte sByte[] = line.getBytes("iso-8859-1");
charBuf = utf8Decoder.decode(isoBuf);
```

What is the easiest way to convert `è­¦å:` to `警告:`?

Thank You
Rich

@Pshemo had the answer I was looking for

```
byte[] isoBytes = line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: `byte[] isoBytes = line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); System.out.println(new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"));` seems to be working fine.

Comment: You can't write any characters above 255 with ISO-8859-1, esp not any Asian characters.  If you have Asian characters, you are not using ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Pshemo  Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for.  My problem was trying to convert the utf8 byte array again.  Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

@Pshemo had the answer I was looking for

```
byte[] isoBytes = line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way would be to save the file as UTF-8 and read it as such.

Most likely the answers you found here already also stated that ISO Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) can't store all the code points that UTF-8 can handle (especially asian characters), thus storing properties (text resources?) as ISO Latin-1 will result in losses.

Thus either store it as UTF-8 or use unicode code points, e.g. `\u8b66\u544a` for `警告` (`Warning` :) ).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a large project and I don't have the ability to do that.  I just need the quick and dirty Java code.

Answer (score 0):

In fact displaying UTF-8 content would yield in ISO-8859-1: è­¦å (plus something). So that is fine.

So the file is in UTF-8. The JDK has the tool [`native2ascii`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) to convert and unconvert to u-escaping non-ASCII characters to `\uXXXX`.

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 old.properties new.properties
```

Use a programmer's editor like JEdit or Notepad++ to be sure of encodings.